# Numpy savetxt file location

Tags: arrays, numpy, csv, google-colaboratory

I'm working in Google Colab and using the following to save a numpy array as a .csv file:

`savetxt('number_of_recordings.csv', number_of_recordings, delimiter=',')`

The code is executing fine, but the only place I can locate the saved file is within the notebook itself.  How do I save the csv file to a different directory so I can access it from outside the notebook?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the CSV.

You can view the files in this tab.

[image]